# Map Shift + F3 in .vimrc

Tags: vim

When using vimgrep with `lv expr path/**`, I like to have a shortcut for navigating the results. So I mapped the <kbd>F3</kbd> key like the following:

```
nnoremap <F3> :lnext<CR>
```

Now I would like to do something like the following

```
nnoremap <SHIFT-F3> :lprevious<CR>
```

But this does not have the desired effect. How do I map a F-key with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>?

**Update:**

The solution is a bit difficult. In terminals you cannot just map <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. In fact an additional line like the following is necessary:

```
set <S-F3>=^[O1;2R
nnoremap <S-F3> :lprevious<CR>
```

But you cannot copy&paste this, see the link below in the right answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're using Vim in the console, not GVIM, right? Anything other than the plain function keys is problematic, and best avoided; try using a prefix like `<Leader>` instead. If you really want this, you can try the instructions at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim for getting function keys with modifiers to work.

Comment: That link was very helpful, I did not even expected a problem like this. Although it is not the answer I wished to read, it is the right answer in my opinion. And following the advise with fast key codes, I could  map the key combination as desired.

Answer (score 18):

It should be `<S-F3>` not `<SHIFT-F3>`, see `:help key-notation` in Vim.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer I wanted to have, but it did not work this way. You need :set for making it in a terminal to work.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays setting extra keycodes for functional keys isn't necessary, all you need is:

```
nnoremap <s-f3> :lprevious<cr>
```

Tested on NeoVim.

Somebody please try it on clean VIM so I could update this answer.

Comment: Doesn't work with neovim on the terminal

Comment: Maybe it's terminal dependent. Works out of the box on up to date Gnome terminal and Neovim.